# Como passo corretamente o tipo de dados por PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, tipagem

No trecho php abaixo, qual é o tipo de PDO::PARAM devo usar  ?

```
$cnx = new PostgreSQL(); //Classe de conexão do banco
$data = '2015-02-13';
$select = 'SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE "data" = :data';
$query -> prepare($select);
$query -> bindParam(":data" , $data , ?)/
$result = $query -> execute();
$result = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A respota da questão é mesmo PDO::PARAM_STR, que conforme foi dito no link que deixo a baixo serve para **string , datas e horas**.

> – PDO::PARAM_STR – para valores strings, datas, horas…
>
> – PDO::PARAM_INT – para valores inteiros
>
> – PDO::PARAM_BOOL – para valor booleano (true ou false)
>
> – PDO::PARAM_NULL – valor nulo (null)
>
> – PDO::PARAM_LOB – representa valores de grande quantidade de dados
>
> – PDO::PARAM_STMT – representa um conjunto de registros, atualmente não é suportado por nenhum driver
>
> – PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT – especifica que é um parâmetro de entrada e saída para “stored procedures”

Fonte:  http://fazer-site.net/pdo-php-data-object/